# Lost context in object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this code:

```
/// global context
function Outer(){
    /// Outer context
    this.print = function(){ 
        console.log("1: "+this) 
        inside(); /// "this" is bound to the global object. Why not bound to the Outer object?
        function inside(){ 
            console.log("2: "+this) 
        } 
   }; 
} 
function print(){
    console.log("3: "+this);
}
var obj = new Outer; 
obj.print(); /// "this" is bound to the Outer object.
print(); /// "this" is bound to the global object.
```

Why inside the method call, `this` has a global object? Can anyone explain this?

Comment: [In a browser and outside of `strict mode`, invoking a function will always bind the value of `this` for the function's scope.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context) If the function is a method (`obj.func()`), it'll point `obj`; otherwise it'll point to `window`. Using [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) or [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) will make console statement 2 print how you'd expect.

Comment: @vox strict mode will only change `window` to `undefined` and not to the Outer object like lexical this from arrow functions. Also note that `print` is already existant and not a good name choice. E.g. on firefox, although being writable, I had issues overwriting it (probably a topic on its own).

Comment: @vox I say:"Why". I did not said:"How to solve". It's different things.

Comment: @MaximPro because that's what the spec says. If your question is "Why does the ECMAScript spec say that" then it's too broad for SO.

Comment: @JaredSmith No question is not too wide! I'm asking a specific place. A competent person can explain. Especially since I saw questions on ECMAScript. Simply if you can not then do not write at all.

Comment: @MaximPro explain why the TC-39 made a specific choice here to bind the `this` context of a top-level function to the global object? Why they then changed their minds and had it be `undefined` in strict mode? There are *pages* of material about this in the meeting notes and the ES discuss threads, this question is just not a good fit for the SO format. Side note: do you think accusing me of incompetence because you don't understand what I wrote is going to make me *less* likely to vote to close your question?

Comment: @JaredSmith 
If you do not answering, and write just so, then this is not a business approach! And even more so to vote for the closure of the matter in general is wretchedly. I do not care if there are normal people they will answer, and will not engage in demagogy about irrelevance!

Answer (score 3):

**That's because, its obeying following 2 JS rules**

- **Rule 1**. In Javascript, new function = new scope - that’s the rule.
- **Rule 2**. When a function is called as a method of an object, `this` is set to the object the method is called on.

**Explanation of the code:**

- For rule 2, `this.print()` is a feature of `Outer` object. So `this` will refer to the Outer object.

So the *console.log 1* will print `1: [object Object]`

- For rule 1, the function `inside()` in Outer is not a feature of Outer object. So new scope will created and `this` assigned to window. And that's also same for the last function 'print()'

So *console.log 2* will print `2: [object Window]`

And *console.log 3* will print `3: [object Window]` as well

Hope Helps,

> Run the code: https://es6console.com/j9bxeati/
>
> Reference: https://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/#function-scope

Answer (score 1):

As [the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) states,

> In most cases, the value of this is determined by how a function is called. It can't be set by assignment during execution, and it may be different each time the function is called. ES5 introduced the bind method to set the value of a function's this regardless of how it's called, and ES2015 introduced arrow functions which do provide their own this binding (it remains the this value of the enclosing lexical context).
>
> <...>
>
> Inside a function, the value of this depends on how the function is called.
>
> <...>
>
> Since the following code is not in strict mode, and because the value of this is not set by the call, this will default to the global object
>
> <...>
>
> So, in strict mode, if this was not defined by the execution context, it remains undefined.

The posted code is not executed in strict mode, so `this` equals to global variable (`window`) inside the function when it's called like `print()`.

If this is not the desirable behaviour, and `print` is expected to be called separately from the object it originally was defined on (e.g. when being passed as a callback), the function can be bound to its lexical `this` with arrow in ES6:

```
function Outer(){
    this.print = () => { ... }; 
}
```

In ES5 `bind` or `self = this` recipe can be used:

```
function Outer(){
    this.print = (function(){ ... }).bind(this);
}

function Outer(){
    var self = this;
    this.print = function(){
      self;
      ...
    };
}
```

If the function isn't expected to be called with another context, it can be called with another context in-place:

```
print.call(this);
```

Or:

```
print.bind(this)();
```

Comment: Your answers how to solve the problem is not the answer to the question "why". You say how to fix. I did not ask you to do this

Comment: The answer cites MDN reference that clearly explains 'why'. I could say same thing with my own words, but it's unlikely that I could say it better. Is there something that remains unclear to you after reading it? The explanation on how to fix the problem comes by default; even if it isn't helpful to you, it will be to someone else who has a similar case.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not obvious for you, that probably means you confuse scope and context of the function.
Scope is what vars function has access to during invocation. Context (this) is determined by how function is invoked.

Now look on how you invoke your function 'inside' and answer the question. Does it vividly owned by any object? That is **why** you have global

Answer (score 0):

> The value of this is determined by how a function is called.

Your "inside" function was called inside "print" function, which has an object reference, but that object did not have "inside" function as a property or that object did not invoke "inside" function.

"this" refers to the object which called it, not the scope in which it is called.
Hence, the global object

Answer (score 0):

the value of `this` is depends on how you are making a call to the intended function and generally leading parent object plays important role in it.

**what does it mean by leading parent object?**:

```
sampleObj.getDetails(); // here 'sampleObj' is the leading parent object for 'getDetails()' function
```

lets try to clear the things using some examples of making call to the function using below sample code snippet.

```
function globalFunction(){
    console.log('global this: ', this);
}
var simpleObj = {
  name : 'john' 
};
var complexObj = {
  outer: function(){
    console.log('outer this: ', this);
  }
}
globalFunction(); // will log global object as no leading parent object is available

complexObj.outer(); // will log 'complexObj' object as leading parent object is 'complexObj'

complexObj.outer = complexObj.outer.bind(simpleObj);
complexObj.outer(); // will log 'simpleObj' object as we have set preference as 'simpleObj' for this **

complexObj.outer.call(); // will log global object as we arent setting any preference for 'this' ***

complexObj.outer.call(simpleObj); // will log simpleObj object as we have set preference as simpleObj for 'this' ***

complexObj.outer.apply(); // will log global object as we arent setting any preference for 'this' ****

complexObj.outer.apply(simpleObj); // will log simpleObj object as we have set preference as simpleObj for 'this' ****
```

hopefully it will help you!

** what is bind: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

*** what is call: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

**** what is apply: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score 0):

You can understand it if you read about [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) new in ES6.

> Until arrow functions, every new function defined its own this value
>   (a new object in the case of a constructor, undefined in strict mode
>   function calls, the base object if the function is called as an
>   "object method", etc.).

Which means that every function defines it's own `this` and in case of a simple function it will always be a global object and not the context of a function it is defined in. Just for comparison a function which doesn't define it's own `this`(an arrow function):

```
/// global context
function Outer(){
    /// Outer context
    this.print = function(){ 
        console.log("1: "+this) 

        let inside = () => { 
            /// "this" is Outer object here
            console.log("2: "+this) 
        } 
        inside(); 
   }; 
}
```